# Assistive Computing

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, accessibility

I find myself suddenly with vision loss  - not 100% but fairly close. I'm wondering if/where there is a good place in SO to discuss ideas/questions/help on assistive technologies. I use a Mac so I could use AskDifferent, but I think some issues cross platform boundaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could ask on multiple sites depending on what exactly it is you want to know :

- [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) : For Mac specific accessibility tools
- [Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) : Tips for improving productivity while on the computer and off
- [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) : For Stack Overflow specific accessibility support
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) : Developing you own accessibility tools
- [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) : For accessibility tools in any OS
- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) : For Ubuntu specific tools

Comment: Super User deals with questions about software in general. This includes (but isn't limited to) Windows, Mac OS X and all Linux distributions.

Comment: I'm going to try posting a question on Super User, and see what kind of responses I get.

Comment: I am getting some good/ interesting responses on SuperUser, so thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Actually that's a pretty good question. It might fit on one of the beta site called [Personnal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/). It does depend how *you formulate the question* though.

> Personal Productivity - Stack Exchange is for people wanting to improve their personal productivity. If you have a question about...

You'd have to formulate it to "improve your productivity with said technologies".

It could fit the [ergonomic part of the site](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/faq). But read the FAQ carefully and read some question examples, to see how this stack work.

Else I really don't know, I've went over the list and haven't really found a site (that is already in beta) that would fit.

Comment: Hugo, PP could work, but their scope seems quite limited. Quote: and it is not about...

problems related to software and automation scripts themselves and not to their application to personal productivity, ask on SuperUser for computer software and Web Applications for online web applications
physical fitness and nutrition, ask on Physical Fitness
lists of software or productivity tools

Answer (score 3):

Any problem or solution regarding computer accessibility ultimately comes down to computer software or hardware, so they will be on topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions), provided that they adhere to the rules outlined in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

Questions about the usage of a specific product clearly fall into the scope of the site. However, asking for a shopping or product recommendation is off topic. If your looking for a program or a device to solve a problem, as long as you can word your question like *How can I achieve X?* instead of *Which program/device should I use for X?*, that's not an issue.

Comment: Thank you all, there are some very helpful comments here. I guess - while my first questions are computer related, for example, is there a reasonable alternative to a keyboard. (I can't find mine :). But I wonder if there are other aspects of life - especially using non-traditional uses of technology - to help me (and others) cope and improve life quality - and for SO, a place where these ideas could be discussed. I know I can use dictation instead of keyboarding for writing letters and email, but for development, this just doesn't work, and im just starting to enjoy development).